# comparison when two consecutive years are selected

Tags: ssas, powerbi, mdx, cubes

I have a power BI dashboard where I am getting data from Live Query so all the calculated measure coming from SSAS cubes. There are two measures which has the calculated data of current year and last year. so when I select the year and month from Power BI slicer it  gives a comparison for both year;this is fine till this point.
But when I select all the months for year 2019 (where it has actually values for Jan,Feb,March) so it should take the data for same months in year 2018 but this is showing all the data for last year in comparison of 3 month data in current year.

Is there any solution in power bi or shall I have to change in MDX measure which is below for last year

([Product Volume],ParallelPeriod([Time].[Year Code Dynamic].[Year Code Dynamic],1,[Time].[Year Code Dynamic].CURRENTMEMBER))

Please advise where I have to change Power BI or MDX

[Data should be here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9nWE.jpg)[whole year is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kENVS.png)

Please advise and ask me in case of any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I think it'll be easier in Power BI to use DAX rather than MDX.

This pattern might help.

```
= TOTALYTD(
   [Your measure],
   DATEADD(
     Calendar[Date]
     ,-12
     ,MONTH
   )
)
```